# Lost email for Twitter

Tags: twitter, password-recovery

I have to reset the password for my Twitter, however I can't remember what email I used for it, I have the login details but the new password has been sent to the email I used to sign up. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has an FAQ on how to recover your account under your circumstances:

https://support.twitter.com/articles/107907-i-don-t-have-access-to-my-account-s-email-address-anymore

Comment: I have checked that but the problem is I have no idea what email I used and the possible ones I could of used, there's no email from twitter about the password reset

Comment: In that case, i believe your only option is to submit a support request at https://support.twitter.com/forms. You may find yourself waiting up to 2 months to get your account back, though.